# How to create and API with lumen to login with Gmail from android app

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, google-signin

I have a mobile app that interacts with my API which is built with the lumen. I want to implement a Google login/register for this app.

My problem is that when I log in with the app to Google, I need to send some kind of token to API and register or login the user

What should I send to API and in the API how can I check the token from Google?

please note that I don't want to log in with lumen, however, I need to get user data from Google using the access token passed by the mobile app.